# HTML Newsletter - Strange line spacing in iOS

Tags: html, iphone, css, newsletter

I am developing a newsletter template. Works well on Outlook2007 but on iPhone I still have some issues. With the following code I try to create a teaser block which contains an image and a text-block (made of a title and a text). In my intent, the text-block should not be higher than the image next to it. In iOS (Apple Mail) an annoying space is added between the title. Anyway idea about how to get rid of it?

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="teaser" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; cursor: pointer; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tr>
<td class="w480 normal-text" height="29" width="92" border="1" valign="top" align="left" style="color: #6f6f6f; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; border: #6f6f6f;">
<img src='testImage.jpg' alt='' />
</td>
<td width="298" valign="top" style="color: #6f6f6f; border: #6f6f6f;">
<h1 style="font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 15px; vertical-align: top; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<a href="http://www.lyra.net/fabio" target="blank" style="color: #6f6f6f; line-height: inherit; text-decoration: none; position: relative; letter-spacing: 0.03em; top: -2px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
Quias alitatem <br />qui cullat
</a>
</h1>
<p class="normal-text no-overflow" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; overflow: hidden; margin: 4px 0px 0px;">
WeeeeFFFFr? Quias alitatem qui cullat lique num et molor sitempo rionse.
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tr>
<td height="52" width="0" style="color: #6f6f6f; border: #6f6f6f;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

P.S. I see there are already similar posts, but as they didn't receive any interesting answer and the markup one uses also makes the difference I decided to post a new questions. I would also love to post screenshots of the problems but it is only possible with reputation > 10

Answer (score 0):

On the table cell of the image, add this: `valign="top"`. It will force the content to the top. In email this works consistently unlike css vertical-align.

Also, `<h1>` and `<p>` tags are best to avoid for consistency. `<font>` tags work best in email.

Comment: Try the changes you suggest but it makes no difference on iOS.

Comment: Remove the height declaration on the first table also.